# why is "append" method not working correctly?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

The "append" method is not working correctly.
It's only going inside the 'if" statement of the "append' method and not entering into the while loop.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=Node()

    def append(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if self.head.data is None:
            self.head=new_node          
        cur_node=self.head
        while cur_node.next is not None:
            cur_node=cur_node.next
        cur_node=new_node

    def insert_after_node(self,prev_node,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if prev_node is None:
            print("node that you have entered does not exist")
        new_node.next=prev_node.next
        prev_node.next=new_node

    def display(self):
        current=self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            print(current.data)
            current=current.next

List=Linkedlist()
List.append("A")
List.append("B")
List.append("C")
List.insert_after_node(List.head,"g")
List.display()
```

Expected output: `AgBC`
Actual Output: `A`

Comment: Your `append` method sets `cur_node` to a bunch of stuff, but ultimately doesn't do anything with it. Did you mean to set `cur_node.next` to something?

Comment: Node instance use data as keyword argument not positional, so first of all you should use Node(data=data) instead of Node(data)

Comment: @om2c0de: no, that's not needed. You can use positional parameters for keyword arguments just fine. Python assigns positional parameters to each argument in order, and the first argument (past `self`, provided by the bound method object), is `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.append()` method simply sets a local variable to `cur_node` to point to `new_node`. This doesn't change the linked list at all; the last node in the link that was previously assigned to that local variable is not changed.

You instead want to assign to the `.next` attribute of the last node:

```
cur_node.next = new_node
```

The `while` loop in the method is working fine otherwise.

You also should *not* use `new_node` twice, when the list is empty. Exit when you don't yet have a head node with data:

```
if self.head.data is None:
    self.head=new_node
    return
```

Personally, I'd set `self.head = None` instead of `self.head = Node()`, then use `if self.head is None:`.

Next, your display function forgets to print the last element. Rather than test for `current.next`, check if `current` is `None`; this is where setting `self.head` to `None` for an empty list would work a lot better:

```
def display(self):
    current = self.head
    while current is not None
        print(current.data)
        current = current.next
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question as you, but my implementation was different and it seems to work just fine.

First I created a node class with all its different methods:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next= new_next
```

The I created my UnorderedList class with its methods too, including append. insert, index and pop I am still working on...

```
class UnorderedList:
    """
    An unordered list class built from a collection of nodes.
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None
    
    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count += 1
            current = current.get_next()

        return count

    def search(self, item):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()

        return found


    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())

    def print_list(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.get_next()

    def append(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)

        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
            return 
            
        current = self.head
        found_last = False
        while not found_last:
            if current.get_next() == None:
                found_last = True
                current.set_next(new_node)
                
            else:
                current = current.get_next()


    def insert(self, item, pos):
        pass


    def index(self, item):
        pass


    def pop(self):
        pass
```

I realize my version of append is more verbose, but I was using the traversal method I previously used as part of my size method to make it work, and it seems to work just fine.

I found it easier to create a Node class with its methods separately as it made it easier to visualize how to set the next node and get data from the current one. Hope this helps!

FYI the node class and a lot of the UnorderedList is straight out of *Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures in Python* by David Ranum and Brad Miller, so I know they work fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=Node()

    def append(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if self.head.data is None:
            self.head=new_node
        else:
            cur_node=self.head
            while cur_node.next is not None:
                cur_node=cur_node.next
            cur_node.next=new_node

    def insert_after_node(self,prev_node,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if prev_node is None:
            print("node that you have entered does not exist")
        new_node.next=prev_node.next
        prev_node.next=new_node

    def display(self):
        current=self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            print(current.data)
            current=current.next
        print(current.data)

List=LinkedList()
List.append("A")
List.append("B")
List.append("C")
List.insert_after_node(List.head,"g")
```

Fixed some bugs for you:

1. The class name `LinkedList` mismatch problem
2. In `append`, `if self.head.data is None`, it should set `self.head` and then return.
3. In the `else` part of `append`, let the last node point to the new node by `cur_node.next=new_node`
4. In `display`, the last node should also be printed.